# Why is it so hard to find numbers with some palindromic properties?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems, data-analysis, palindrome

Lets start by defining palindromes and then looking at some problems;

> We can define the set $P_d$ as set of all palindromes with $d$ digits.
>
> If $p\in P_d$, then $p=(x,y)$, where $x$ is the numerical value of the
>   palindrome and $y$ is the number base in which we can write $x$ to be
>   palindromic. Then $x,y\in\mathbb N, y\ne1$ .
>
> $$P_d=\{ (x,y) : x=\sum_{n=1}^{d}a_ny^{d-n}, a_n\in\{0\dots y-1\},a_1\ne0,a_n=a_{d-n+1},y\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\} \}$$

Is there anything out there that one can use to inspect the nature of these sets? 
(see question examples below)

---

### Some problem examples

Now, when trying to find palindromes in *consecutive number bases*, the following questions remain unsolved (and all progress that I'm aware of is based on or comes from computed data):

**Q1:** [Is there a number nontrivially palindromic in $b\ge4$ consecutive number bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234587/can-a-number-be-palindrome-in-4-consecutive-number-bases)

$(*)$ *We can only observe odd $d$ as even palindromes in base $b$ are divisible by $b+1$ .*

That is, is there a $P_d$ in which we have pairs $(x,y),(x,y+1),(x,y+2),(x,y+3),\dots$ ?

It would seem that there isn't as $P_3$ seems to be the only set containing infinitely many cases of:

 Both pairs $(x,y),(x,y+3)$ along with either of $(x,y+1),(x,y+2)$ for some $x,y$, so far.

And $P_3$ can't have all four pairs (see the question link) - but this is still not fully proven.

**Q2:** Find all numbers palindromic in $3$ consecutive number bases?

*($d=1$ is trivial and thus not being observed as one digit numbers are always palindromes)*

I believe I've found all solutions (infinitely many for each $d$ digit case so far) for $d=3,5,7$ digits, but I can't find a single solution for $d\ge9$ digit examples so far.

These are shown in the [MO version of the previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268590/can-a-number-be-palindromic-in-more-than-3-consecutive-number-bases).

**Q3:** Find all numbers palindromic in $2$ consecutive number bases?

I've found all solutions for [$d=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516564/find-palindromes-in-two-consecutive-number-bases) and I believe similar expressions can be used for $d=5$, but I have no idea how to fully define the patterns showing in $d\ge7$.

*(But this solutions for $d=3$ are still based on computed data, not reached algebraically)*

I've tried to observe the gaps between solutions when they are split in number bases $y$ and sorted according to the size of $x$, and noticed a "branching tree like pattern" [emerging in $d=7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520460/unexpected-pattern-in-consecutive-7-digit-double-palindromes). A similar pattern emerges in $d=9$, but has much more "branching" spots that occur more often, and when observing the exact gaps, I've managed to extract [few patterns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541817/predict-gaps-between-9-digit-2-palindromes) but only for the first few out of hundreds more that start appearing as $y$ grows.

**Q4:** Find all numbers palindromic simultaneously in bases $y,y+2$ ?

Again, I've managed to observe patterns for $d=3,5$ in gaps between the solutions, but I don't see how I can fully define $d\ge7$ so far. (There are some repeating gaps in $d=7,9$, but the pattern isn't fully clear).

You can see the [gaps here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzrXQ0KW85Nl3jBdk2mA28CIRZxwa3Sq/view?usp=sharing) for $d=3,5,7,9,11$ where "`.`"s represent solutions , and the numbers in `[]` are gaps - the number of palindromes between the solutions.

*(download and open the v2.html in browser to show the text without the linebreaks)*

---

### Question

All the progress on these is based on computed data and searching for patterns.

> Is there a way to reach (prove) any of the progress on any of these or
>   similar problems algebraically? *(without previously observing the
>   data and patterns)*

For example, how wold you algebraically reach those found polynomial expressions for $3$ consecutive bases in **Q2** for $d=3,5,7$? Why is it so hard to show that those are the only ones that exist?

Simpler example, is there a $d\ge9$ digit number which is simultaneously palindromic in $3$ consecutive number bases? I believe there should be, as $d=3,5,7$ have infinitely many examples.

> **How can this or similar problems be effectively approached?**
>
> Or if not algebraically, can we extract patterns from these problems
>   more effectively?

Or are mathematicians uninterested in these kind of problems, so I'm not finding anything on problems of this nature out there?

*P.S. motivation behind this comes out since when I don't know how to solve something completely, but I'm able to get some insights into it, it gets more interesting to waste time on.*

Additional examples: is there a number base in which there exists a non palindromic number $x$ whose fifth power is palindromic, $x^5$? Or regarding only the third power and [base $10$ and number $2201$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434030/is-2201-really-the-only-non-palindromic-number-whose-cube-is-palindromic)? Why is it so hard to prove these observations?

Comment: Well, I guess you'll just have to find and ask the people who find that interesting. Since "palindrome" depends on the number base, and not even most religions claim that there is a god-given number base (with one exception, but that's in a world I invented, so...), most people don't think that's a relevant property. It should be easy to locate the fifty or so people who don't think so.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That's one of the reasons why I'm mostly considering only problems that consider *all number bases* - to not depend on a single number base. Separation into $d$ digit sets is to make things easier to observe and extend patterns to higher digits once patterns for smaller digits are established, but I'm having trouble in doing so. But I figure this is still mostly uninteresting to general community as you mention.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. BTW, I didn't intend offense, I've answered such questions occasionally... but only if it could be extended to other number bases, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268833/why-is-987654321-123456789-almost-exactly-8/2268950#2268950).